# get row count according to the month in the date in Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I want a query in laravel to group by data with dateofSale's month with the count of rows with the same month.

here is my table
[image]

and I want to output something like this

> ```
> numberOfSales | Month
>      2           Nov
>      1           Oct
> ```

how can I do it?

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: it is Laravel 5.7.12

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you have a Model set up for this table or are you just using the `DB` (Query Build)?

Comment: yes i set a model and tried to get data in a controller

Comment: What's the model name??

Comment: it is SalesData. DB name is agency

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to achieve this what you're after with:

```
$data = \App\SaleData::selectRaw('COUNT(*) as count, YEAR(dateOfSale) year, MONTH(dateofSale) month')
    ->groupBy('year', 'month')
    ->get();
```

If you don't include the year as well then you'll have sales from different years included in the same month e.g. sales from October 2017 and October 2018 will be included together.

Comment: i tried this.when i check it with dd($data) it doesn't give the output

Comment: @PasinduSenarath As in it doesn't give you the desired output or it doesn't give you any output?

Comment: it doesn't give any

Comment: @PasinduSenarath Do you get any results with `\App\SaleData::all();`?

Comment: yeah. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53465623/laravel-chart-doesnt-get-the-data-from-the-controller check this out. i check your query by using die and dump command.. it doesn't give it.. please help :(

Comment: @PasinduSenarath What field type are you using for `dateOfSale` in your database? What database and version are you using?

Comment: it is date type. database version means? wampsever version?

Comment: @PasinduSenarath As in are you using MySQL, SqlSvr Sqlite? And what version of the database are you using e.g. if it's MySQL are you using 5.6? The code I gave you should work as I tested it before I put it in my answer so I'm trying to figure out why it doesn't give you any results.

Comment: @PasinduSenarath Yeah, out-of-the-box tinker will use the same code and database as your main app.

Comment: query now works when it test it in tinker. :) can't you help me with the other one? :)

Comment: why i doesn't give the data to graph?

Answer (score 0):

you can try as

```
$data = SalesData::select(DB::raw('count('*') as `count`'), DB::raw('MONTH(dateOfSale) month'))
         ->groupBy(function($m) {
             return Carbon::parse($m->dateOfSale)->format('m');
         })->get();
```

don't forget to import carbon and DB on top of your controller like

```
use DB;
use Carbon\Carbon;
```

Comment: i get an error saying Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Model' not found

Comment: change model keyword with your model name

Comment: i did.then it gives error , Class 'App\Http\Controllers\DB' not found

Comment: `GroupBy` should be `'month'` not a closure.

Comment: i think it will not get the month in group by. if its work then i will update my answer

Comment: "A non-numeric value encountered" I get this error with your code

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to import your Models in your controller.
just like this
[image]

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33992757)

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend you to use standardized timestamps in your 'dateofSale' field. This way you have access to more native solutions to your application. In this case, the answer to this problem is simply:

```
ModelName::query()
->whereMonth('created_at', '9')
->count();
```