# laravel chart doesn't get the data from the controller

Tags: laravel, highcharts, controller

i'm trying to get data to chart from the database.
this how i wanted the data from database
   [get row count according to the month in the date in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53461005/get-row-count-according-to-the-month-in-the-date-in-laravel/53461299?noredirect=1#comment93801937_53461299)

so i add that query. this is how controller looks like

```
class DashboardController extends Controller
    {
    public function admin()
    {

        $suppliers = SupplierData::all();
        $repcounter= SalesRep::count();
        $totalsales= SalesData::count();
        $totalrevenue=SalesData::sum('total_price');



        $chartdata = SalesData::selectRaw('COUNT(*) as count, YEAR(dateOfSale) year, MONTH(dateofSale) month')
            ->groupBy('year', 'month')
            ->get();

        $chart=Charts::database($chartdata,'bar','highcharts')
            ->title("Sales Details")
            ->elementLabel("Total Sales")
            ->dimensions(1000,500)
            ->responsive(false);

        return view('dashboard', compact('suppliers','repcounter','totalsales','totalrevenue','chart'));
    }
```

and here is my html code part

```
<div>
    {!!    $chart->html() !!}
        </div>
```

but this gives me empty chart. i don't know where i got it wrong. this is how it shows.

[image]

**edited**
here is the console error,

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'querySelectorAll' of null
    at Object.c.createSvg (chartist.min.js:8)
    at e.d [as createChart] (chartist.min.js:8)
    at e.h (chartist.min.js:8)
```

Comment: Have you checked your browser console for any errors?

Comment: here i edited this post with the error. how to fix this